cannot install or upgrade python packages using pip
I have been using Pycharm professional and havent such a problem til date. But over the last 3 or 4 days I have not been able to create new venv's that can install new packages or upgrade older versions of base packages like pip itself using pip.
I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/build_env.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.rich.console import (
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ._log_render import FormatTimeCallable, LogRender
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/_log_render.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .text import Text, TextType
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/text.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ._wrap import divide_line
  File "/Users/lokranjan/PycharmProjects/mcts/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/_wrap.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cells import cell_len, chop_cells

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.rich.cells'

I have tried the following.

reinstalled Python 3.10 and 3.12
Cleared caches
Reindexed my interpreter
reinstalled pip


This question is similar to: pip3 install not working - No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
